# Python: Dictionary inside get()

Tags: python, dictionary

first post!
I am slowly working my way through Automate the Boring Stuff with Python and am just doing a bit of experimentation with the get() method and dictionaries (chapter 5). I have written a small piece of code to tell me the capital of the country that I type in or, if it's not in my dictionary, that the capital city is "not available".

However, the response "not available" is appearing even when I input countries that are included in my dictionary. Any insights about what is going on here? I tried Googling about using dictionaries inside the get() method but didn't find much that explained the issue. Code as follows:

```
capitals = {'Australia': 'Canberra', 'England': 'London', 'South Africa': 'Pretoria'}
print('Choose country')
country = input()
print('The capital of ' + country + ' is ' 
      + capitals.get(capitals[country], 'not available'))
```

Comment: Modify your get like: `capitals.get(country, 'not available')`

Comment: `capitals[country]` *already retrieves the value for the key `country`*, which you then pass to `capitals.get(..., 'not available')`. But since `...` will be a *capital*, it won't be in the `dict`. You want `capitals.get(country, 'not available')`. In other words, `some_dict.get(some_key)` is equivalent to `some_dict[some_key]` except `.get` will return a default value if the key isn't in the dict, wheras indexing into the dict will throw an error

Comment: Show your input. You have a problem that is hiding another problem, which is that you don't normalize the case of the input.

Comment: Thank you - working well now!

Comment: @Foz. It is good practice to accept the answer that helps you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` method *replaces* `__getitem__` (which you normally access via bracket notation). `capitals.get(capitals[country], 'not available')` is actually performing two lookups:

1. `capitals[country]` finds the capital, e.g. Canberra.
2. `capitals.get(...)` then looks up the name of the capital as the country. There are very few cases where this *won't* fail.

If you look up a country that does not exist, `capitals[country]` will just raise a `KeyError`.

What you probably meant to do was

```
capitals.get(country, 'not available')
```

One more consideration you may want to address is that Python dictionaries are case sensitive. You probably want to get `Canberra` back whether you pass in `Australia`, `australia`, or `aUstrAlIA`. The standard way of doing this is to make the keys of the dictionary all lowercase, and then look up with either the lowercase or [case-folded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) version:

```
capitals = {'australia': 'Canberra', 'england': 'London', 'south africa': 'Pretoria'}
country = input('Choose country: ')
print('The capital of', country, 'is', capitals.get(country.casefold(), 'not available'))
```

Notice that I replaced the first `print` with an argument to `input`, and removed the `+` operators in the second `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Synax for get() method:

```
dict.get(key, default = None)
```

**key** in your dictionary is country like 'Australia'.

In your code:

```
capitals.get(capitals[country], 'not available')
```

`capitals[country]` is not the key, you need to use it like this code:

```
capitals.get(country, 'not available')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple edit on the code above:

```
capitals = {'Australia': 'Canberra', 'England': 'London', 'South Africa': 'Pretoria'}
country = input('Insert country > ').title()
output = capitals.get(country, 'Not Available in Dict')
print(f'The capital of {country} is {output}')
```

Here are the edits :

- Use the `.title()` method to convert any country name entered into a "title" format so it will match the naming format in the dictionary
- Create a variable to store the capital name="key value" before printing it out. The variable here is `output`